# How can I make my iPod Touch home button more responsive?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

I am finding that lately, quite often pushing my iPod Touch's home button doesn't generate any response - I have to push it again really hard. I'm not sure if it's an issue with the OS or with the hardware.

I haven't jailbroken, and my iPod touch is a new 4th Gen 8GB model bought in September 2011.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unresponsive iPhone/iPod Touch home button is a known problem. I had an iPhone which started with the same problem as yours. At first the home button worked with just a soft touch, and from any angle. Then it started to work only with a hard press and not at all from certain angles. Finally, it either completely ignored presses, or responded to a single press as if it had been pressed twice (multitasking bar appeared).

It was still inside the one-year warranty, but I bought AppleCare anyway, figuring that it might recur. I took it to an Apple Store and the guy played with it for a minute, told me I had a faulty device and gave me a brand new iPhone. The home button can't be replaced, so they just give you a new one.

My advice it to take it to an Apple Store if there's one nearby, or if not call Apple and report the problem. Most likely you'll get a new, working iPod Touch.

Answer (score 1):

This should not be the case.

If this is not responding as it should, and providing you have not got it wet (which will often cause a poor response form home button) you should take it back to the shop you bought it in and have them replace it.

The option they have is to either replace or repair it. This is really where you should go first.

However Apple have a very good customer service policy, and their stores are owned by Apple and not franchised distributers, which means that you are dealing with the manufacturer directly and they are very likely to just replace the device for a new one, or a refurbished one.

Answer (score 1):

if home button stopped working...

- go to settings->general->accessibility
- turn on AssistiveTouch in the Physical & Motor section near bottom
- A little round home button appears!
- Double click it for the multitsask bit
- click it to select home and other options.

Answer (score 0):

If pushing the button harder *does* have an effect, this should be a hardware - not a software problem, IMHO. You could return your iPod.
Apple's products are covered by a **[limited 1 year world wide gurantee](http://store.apple.com/Catalog/uk/Images/worldwidewarranty.html)**.

Here are guides from [support.apple.com](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2802?viewlocale=en_EN&locale=en_EN) explaining how to troubleshoot home button problems:

> #### The Home button is slow to respond
>
> 1. If the Home button is slow to
>      respond when exiting one application, try another application.
> 2. If the
>      issue exists only in certain applications, try removing and
>      reinstalling those applications. For further assistance in installing
>      and troubleshooting applications see [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1702).
> 3. If the issue
>      continues, Try turning iPhone off and then on again. If the iPhone
>      will not restart, [try resetting it](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1430).
> 4. If the issue is still happening,
>      [try to restore the iPhone](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414).
> 5. Seek service is the issue is still
>      occurring.
>
> #### The Home button is not working
>
> 1. Put the iPhone to sleep.
> 2. Wait a couple of seconds.
> 3. Press the Home button.
> 4. iPhone should wake
>      up.
> 5. If iPhone does not wake up, then iPhone should be serviced.

Comment: Most could jump to this "If iPhone does not wake up, then iPhone should be serviced."

Answer (score 0):

Something I do which seems to work is to open an Apple app (notes, weather etc.) hold down the sleep/ wake button until slide to power off appears then hold the home button until the screen clears. This works when my iPad's home button plays up.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem. It appears to be completely non functioning at this time.  Today I went to the apple store in the local mall.  They will completely replace the entire ipod 4 and give me a brand new one for $99!  Not too bad considering I paid almost $400 for it brand new.  But in the meantime, they placed a VIRTUAL HOME button on the screen of my ipod! Works great!! Now I can access everything and don't have to worry about the home key.  So, before I do the trade, I am going to be satisfied with the Virtual home key.  It might be an app, not really sure, as a worker at Apple installed it on mine.

Comment: It's called AssistiveTouch and it's part of the Accessibility options in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was doing the same thing..frustrating ..had a can of aerosol contact cleaner from The Source..gave the iPod 4 a super quick spray into the opening on the bottom where the USB cord plugs in and it instantly works like new.. No more pushing and holding to get it to do anything

Answer (score 0):

I've also used the drop of water trick in the past and it worked on my iPad. I tried the same on my iPhone a few times since I was having the same issue but it never seemed to make a difference. I finally stopped by the apple store and they swapped out my phone for another one. It wasn't within warranty, but the guy said the issue was a common one. Might be worth giving your local Apple store a try if the issue persists.

Answer (score -1):

Put on drop of water on the home button and press it and move your finger in circles  ... If it's dust what made the problem .. It will go away .... If it doesn't response then you have to change your home button  ....
I fixed my home bottom using one drop of water
..... I hope It work for you too
Peace ....